# Trying to do a local build with TeamCity in VS 2008

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, teamcity, visual-studio-2008-sp1

After an emergency rebuild of my machine last week (16 months development caught up with it) I am nursing it back to operational use.

We use a TeamCity buildserver to run a local build before checking the code into subversion.

However Teamcity is giving an annoying error about there being no subversion resources. I've even done a fresh source code checkout just to make sure it wasn't right.

> Failed to collect pending changes in Subversion.
>
> Error: Opened solution contains no Subversion versioned resources

I hate it when something gets in between me and enhancing customer value.

Comment: By "local build", are you referring to using the [Pre-tested commit](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Pre-Tested+%28Delayed%29+Commit)  (remote run) feature in Teamcity?

Comment: We must have slipped into the vernacular, but yes a Pre-tested commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try [fresh 6.5.x bugfix update](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2011/12/09/teamcity-6-5-6-bugfix-update/), where [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-18704) (annoying error) was fixed.
Full Subversion 1.7 support will be avaliable in [TeamCity 7.0](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/TeamCity+EAP).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been down to using Tortoise 1.7 to checkout the code, and the TeamCity Visual Studio plugin from our TeamCity 5.0 version couldn't read the updated svn files

So uninstalled new Tortoise, reinstalled old Tortoise, and then checkout the code base again, and it all works!